# Passing data between mouse events

Tags: javascript, events, mouse

How can one pass events between mousedown and mouseup specifically? In my mousedown event I create a circle and add it to the DOM, in my mouseup I want to animate the circle. I was hoping to do this by referencing the node without attaching an ID, if possible.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
// Mouse down
hitArea.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  var el = new createCircle();

  mask.appendChild(el);

  TweenMax.set(el, {
    transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
    x: e.clientX - hitDimensions.left, 
    y: e.clientY - hitDimensions.top
  });
});

// Mouse up
hitArea.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {

  // Reference to el needed
  animateCircle(el, e);

});
```

You can view my in progress code here: http://codepen.io/getreworked/pen/VjzyLL

Answer (score 1):

You can just use closures:

```
var el;
hitArea.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  el = new createCircle();

  mask.appendChild(el);

  TweenMax.set(el, {
    transformOrigin: '50% 50%',
    x: e.clientX - hitDimensions.left, 
    y: e.clientY - hitDimensions.top
  });
});

// Mouse up
hitArea.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {

  if(el)
     animateCircle(el, e);

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not that easy because each click creates a new circle the reference would be overwritten. I could create an array and push a new array item each time, but then I have to keep track of the array items to add/remove them as we go. I was hoping for a simpler solution

Comment: It's probably not a problem because of `mousedown` and `mouseup` are pair events. If I wrong could you explain which side effects it may cause? P.S. it seems it works fine on your codepen

Comment: The problem with that approach is it loses reference. So when removing the element from the DOM, it will only have reference to the current element. You'll notice when the elements are removed from the #mask group in the SVG, one circle will always remain in the group. It should be empty. Oddly, all other new elements get removed, though I'd have expected only the current one to be removed